# Running a Single Test using Maven

Tags: testing, maven, selenium

i want to run a single test using maven 
here's my pom.xml :

junit
      junit
      4.8.1
      test
    
    
        org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers
        selenium-java-client-driver
        1.0.2

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

WebTestAutomatisation
  
  
       org.apache.maven.plugins
       maven-war-plugin
       2.0.2

```
     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
  </plugin>



     <!--  Start the tomcat server and  Deploy the war -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
        <configuration>

    <fork>true</fork>
        <wait>false</wait>
            <container>
 <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
 <type>installed</type>
  <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
   </container>
  <!-- <executions>
  <execution>
 <id>start-container</id>
  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
  <goal>start</goal>
   <goal>deploy</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
 <execution>
  <id>stop-container</id>
 <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>stop</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
 </executions> -->
</configuration>
```

```
 <!-- Start the selenium server -->
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.3</version>

  <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>start</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>start-server</goal>
   </goals>
  <configuration>
   <background>true</background>
   <logOutput>true</logOutput>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
 <execution>
```

stop
      post-integration-test
    
     stop-server
     
    
   
    
      
    
     org.apache.maven.plugins
     maven-surefire-plugin
      2.4.3
    
      
     org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit
       
    
     
    **/functional/*Test.java

```
 <!--   Running the tests in the functional tests package
      during the integration tests phase. -->
 <id>integration-tests</id>
 <phase>integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
<goal>test</goal>
```

false
    
     none
    
    
     **/functional/*Test.java

```
</project>
```

i used this command : `mvn -Dtest=MyTestClass test`
and i get this error :

i tried this command but it runs all tests and not the specified one  `mvn -Dit.test=MyTestClass verify`

Comment: Do you try to run a single test case or all testcases within a single class? Furthermore you are using a really old version of maven-surefire-plugin (recent one: 2.12) and for integration tests you should use the maven-failsafe-plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise i try to run a single test class

Comment: For the parameter you have given the maven-failsafe-plugin is needed. But i don't see it in your pom excerpts. Furthermore if you are trying to run integration tests you need to go to the correct lifecycle (mvn verify instead of mvn test), cause mvn test is only responsilbe for running unit tests.

Comment: i used verify like this mvn -Dit.test=MyTestClass verify but it runs all the tests

Comment: You mean the unit tests? How did you named you test classes: For unit tests Test*.java, *Test.java or *TestCase.java for Integration test: IT*java, *IT.java or *ITCase.java. Furthermore i've got the impression you didn't understand the destinction between unit and integration tests, cause your configuration only supports unit tests (maven-surefire; very old version) but you like to execute an integration test via it.test=.. you should use in this case -Dtest=MyTestClass.

Comment: @khmarbaise i'm writing selenium tests so it's functional tests

Comment: Which means in other words no unit tests and the maven-failsafe-plugin is responsible for those tests.

Comment: @khmarbaise please have you some useful links or eBooks to understand this well . thank you in advance

Comment: First the sonatype books: http://sonatype.com/Support/Books/ and furthermore http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/

Answer (score 0):

[Jute maven plugin](https://github.com/raydac/jute) allows to execute single JUnit test as external JVM process